# Samba multiple file permission masks

Tags: vagrant, samba

I'm running windows 7 and using samba with vagrant/virtualbox/ubuntu (all latest).  Most of the files in my share are standard code with permission 0664, so in the config I've set `create mask = 0664` and that's working great.  However I've got a sprinkling of bash files with permission 0755.  Most of the time they are in directories with other files that are 0664, so I can't just reconfigure entire directories in my config (nor do I want to keep track of all the directories).  Is there some way I can apply a permission to files of a specific extension?  Or even better have samba somehow maintain file permissions when saving?

As an aside, I'm using sublime (v3065) on windows to edit the files on my share, so perhaps if it's not doable in the smb config I could modify sublime's properties to do it?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no way to set samba create masks specifically per file extension. I don't know if Sublime has a way, but I doubt it. There is also no way to set Umask to do this.

In this case, what I would do is create a simple bash script to find .sh / .bash files, and chmod them. Then cron schedule that script to run every (n) minutes. The cpu bandwidth of such a script will be negligible.

If you are not sure how to write the script, or schedule it, let me know and I will show you.

There could be a better answer out there, but at least for now this will solve the problem.

:-)